# Make a simple Firefox extension - Inject content

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I developped a few days ago a chrome extension by Inject content. This means that I didn't use any Google chrome browser logic, api or whatever. I create a simple `manifest.json` that loaded my `extension-loader.js` which injected scripts into the browser using `appendChild` into the `head` html element.

I want to do basically the same thing for a firefox extension, but everything I have found so far seems rather complicated, explaining how to use API and a lot of stuff I don't want nor need to use.

In chrome I used `web_accessible_resources` to load the scripts I wanted to inject. (libraries and my own logic)

So my question is simple. How to create a simple firefox extension that loads other scripts, present in the extension, into the browser page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("my-script.js")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already Firefox addon **Greasemonkey** that is designed to load other scripts into browser pages. So you just need to write greasemonkey script that will act as Chrome extension.